# Deleting a specified object inside an array in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Using Angular typescript, I am getting a json array object. I want to delete an object that I specified in the object I received. But it never deletes it.

```
addCategorySub(categorySub: CategorySubModel, index: number) {
  categorySub.id = categorySub.id.toString().trim();

  this.categorySubService.postCategorySub(categorySub)
    .subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        //this.categorySubList.push(response.data);
        //this.categorySubList = [...this.categorySubList];

        this.categoryList[0].categorySubs.push({
          categoryId: response.data.categoryId,
          createdDate: response.data.createdDate,
          id: response.data.id,
          name: response.data.name,
          totalCount: response.data.totalCount,
          updatedDate: response.data.updatedDate
        });
        this.categoryList = [...this.categoryList]
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: `${categorySub.name}.`, life: constants.TOAST_SUCCESS_LIFETIME});
        this.messageService.clear('c');

        //this.categoryList = this.categoryList.filter((p) => p.id !== categorySub.id).filter((p) => p.id !== undefined);
        //this.categoryList[index] = this.categoryList[categorySub.id];
        //delete this.categoryList[categorySub.id]

        //this.categoryList = this.categoryList.filter((p) => p.categorySubs.filter((x) => x.id !== categorySub.id).splice(categorySub.id, 1));

        console.log(this.categoryList)

      },
      error: (e) => {
        this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Hata', detail: `not record \n${e}`, life: constants.TOAST_ERROR_LIFETIME});
        this.messageService.clear('c');
        }
      })
  }
```

For example, I want to delete data number 27.
[image]

```
  export class CategoryModel {
    id: number | any;
    name: string | any;
    companyId: number | any;
    createdDate: Date | undefined;
    updatedDate: Date | undefined;
    totalCount: number | any;
    categorySubs: CategorySubModel[] = []; //any;
  }

  export class CategorySubModel {
    id: number | any;
    name: string | any;
    categoryId: number | any;
    createdDate: Date | undefined;
    updatedDate: Date | undefined;
    totalCount: number | any;
  }
```

json object points to categorySubs sub. So I want to delete from here

For example I have a json object below, I want to delete some selected data in this json object

```
  [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Yazıcı",
        "businessCode": 0,
        "totalCount": 1,
        "createdDate": "2023-03-01T06:08:13.9752895",
        "updatedDate": "2023-03-13T10:00:42.4496853",
        "companyId": 3,
        "categorySubs": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Mobil Yazıcı",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-01T07:17:39.6269764",
                "updatedDate": "2023-03-13T10:00:15.8128449",
                "categoryId": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Lazer Yazıcı3",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-01T07:17:44.0560564",
                "updatedDate": "2023-03-13T10:00:50.2878444",
                "categoryId": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Nokta Vuruşlu Yazıcı",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-01T07:18:01.0370904",
                "updatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "categoryId": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 4070,
                "name": "asd",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T12:59:55.9999323",
                "updatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "categoryId": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 4071,
                "name": "tert",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T13:07:20.3666421",
                "updatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "categoryId": 3
            },
            {
                "id": "31",
                "name": "wq",
                "companyId": 3,
                "categoryId": 3
            },
            {
                "categoryId": 3,
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T13:13:43.5022618Z",
                "id": 4072,
                "name": "wq",
                "updatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Do you try to get rid of it ? Where is the line where you tried to do it (with keyword `delete` for example) ? Or else : is there a reason why you just don't delete the line where this info is added (This line that contains this : `id: response.data.id,`) ?

Comment: If i understood your question, what you want is to delete specific item in your array right? I tried that some time ago and i ended by just creating another array with all items without the specified one. You can use lambda methods to reach that.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good. Yes I want to delete data in an array. I want to remove-delete a value that I specified in categoryList.

Comment: I added a json object above. I want to delete an object that I selected in categorySubs under this json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const item = this.categoryList[0].categorySubs.find(category => category.id === 8);
if (item) {
    const index = this.categoryList[0].categorySubs.indexOf(item);
    this.categoryList[0].categorySubs.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: error TS18048: 'item' is possibly 'undefined'. It gave an error like this, how can I bypass it?

Comment: You can check it before using it.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the item, find the index of the item in your array, then use the slice function.

```
public deleteSubCategory(subCategoryId: number) {

  const subCategoryIndex = this.categoryList[0].categorySubs.findIndex(subCategory => subCategory.id === subCategoryId);
  
  // if a matching id item is available then above code will return an index 0 or greater

  if (subCategoryIndex > -1) {
    this.categoryList[0].categorySubs.splice(subCategoryIndex, 1);
  }

  // some UI component libraries require you to reconstruct the array,
  // to pick up the new changes in the array
  // in that case you have to do one more step

  this.categoryList = Object.assign([], this.categoryList); 
}
```

You can bind the above `deleteSubCategory()` function to `click` event on each of your category. Upon clicking the delete button, emit the category's id to the function.